# How to Import Part of an SVN Repository into Bazaar

Tags: svn, bzr

### The Situation

I am running bazaar 2.4.1

A 'project hosting' company hosts my svn repository for `Project A` at:

```
https://svn.example.com/myrepo/trunk/ProjectA/
```

I do not have svn-admin access to the repo at `svn.example.com`.

Within the `projectA` repo, there is a directory that holds all the code for `Component X`. Its svn location is:

```
https://svn.example.com/myrepo/trunk/ProjectA/ComponentX
```

### The Goal

I am trying to split off `Component X` from `Project A`'s SVN repo to become `Project B`. Where `Project B` is versioned in Bazaar.

### The Plan

My plan is to:

1. Create a local bzr repository for `Project B`
2. Use `bzr svn-import` to import `Component X` from `Project A` into my local `Project B`
3. Then, push `Project B` to Launchpad
4. Then, `svn-delete` the old `Component X` direcotry from the svn repo.

I am stuck at step 2.

### So far so good

So, on my Windows XP, I have created a bzr repo for `Project B`:

```
# cd C:\me\OpenSource\
# bzr init-repo ProjectB
```

Then, I moved into that directory:

```
# cd ProjectB
```

### It goes a bit wrong

Then, I tried to `bzr svn-import` to grab the svn directory:

```
# bzr svn-import https://svn.example.com/myrepo/trunk/ProjectA/ComponentX/
```

This, however, generates an error:

```
bzr: ERROR: The specified path is inside a branch. Specify a different URL or a
different repository layout (see also 'bzr help svn-layout').
```

I have tried various things and keep getting the same error.

### Things I have tried

**Tried: Modifying subversion.conf to indicate that ComponentX is a branch**

After looking at `'bzr help svn-layout'`, I have modified `C:\Documents and Settings\Me\Application Data\bazaar\2.0\subversion.conf` and added a line to indicate that `/ComponentX` should be treated as a branch:

```
[203ae883-c723-44c9-aabd-cb56e4f81c9a]
branches = */ComponentX
```

That did not work. Same error:

```
bzr: ERROR: The specified path is inside a branch. Specify a different URL or a
different repository layout (see also 'bzr help svn-layout').
```

**Tried: Specifying a different repository layout as an argument**

i.e. passing it as an argument: `--layout=root` (Because I wanted that path to be treated as root of the new bzr repo):

```
# bzr svn-import --layout=root https://svn.example.com/myrepo/trunk/ProjectA/ComponentX/
```

That did not work. Same error:

```
bzr: ERROR: The specified path is inside a branch. Specify a different URL or a
different repository layout (see also 'bzr help svn-layout').
```

So, I tried just saying `--layout=none`:

```
# bzr svn-import --layout=none https://svn.example.com/myrepo/trunk/ProjectA/ComponentX/
```

That did not work. Same error:

```
bzr: ERROR: The specified path is inside a branch. Specify a different URL or a
different repository layout (see also 'bzr help svn-layout').
```

To be honest I'm hacking now.

I just do not know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svn-import is specifically targetted at importing all branches in a Subversion repository. The --layout option is used to specify what it considers a branch. It seems you're trying to clone a single branch, for which "bzr branch" is indeed the correct command.

To explain the layouts:

Asterisks in the  "branches = " setting don't traverse more than one level of directories. Setting "branches = trunk/*/ComponentX" in subversion.conf would be the correct value. It seems like the error from bzr-svn is a bit confusing though. Really, it should be saying that the path you've specified doesn't contain any branches.

This means that --layout=root will merely make it consider https://svn.example.com/myrepo a branch. This explains why you get the error about specifying a branch inside of a path.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to my own question.

Instead of battling with `bzr svn-import`, circumvent the problem by using `bzr branch` instead. It does not really answer the questions why `bzr svn-import` is throwing errors, but solves the problem.

So, in the situation where a 'project hosting' company is hosting your svn repository for `Project A` at:

```
https://svn.example.com/myrepo/trunk/ProjectA/
```

and within the `projectA` repo, there is a directory that holds all the code for `Component X`. Its svn location is:

```
https://svn.example.com/myrepo/trunk/ProjectA/ComponentX
```

and where the goal is to split off `Component X` from `Project A`'s SVN repo to become `Project B`. Where `Project B` is versioned in Bazaar.

The plan should be to:

1. Create a local bzr repository for `Project B`
2. Use `bzr branch` to dump `Component X` from `Project A` into my local `Project B`
3. Then, push `Project B` to Launchpad
4. Recommended: Don't forget to svn-delete the `Component X` from `Project A` to avoid duplication.

Like so:

**1. Create a local bzr repository for `Project B`**

So, on my Windows XP, I create a bzr repo for `Project B`:

```
# cd C:\me\OpenSource\
# bzr init-repo ProjectB
```

Then, move into that directory:

```
# cd ProjectB
```

**2. Use `bzr branch` to dump `Component X` from `Project A` into my local `Project B`**

Then, create a local branch from the svn repo sub-directory:

```
# bzr branch https://svn.example.com/myrepo/trunk/ProjectA/ComponentX/ ComponentX
```

**3. Then, push `Project B` to Launchpad**

Then, push it to create the launchpad-hosted branch as per [the instructions in the bazaar docs](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/tutorials/using_bazaar_with_launchpad.html#publishing-your-changes):

```
# bzr push lp:~mylaunchpadteam/mylaunchpadproject/trunk
```

Then, perhaps tweak the directory structure and add files to convert it into a 'project'.

Comment: to be honest, i'd have just used svn export and thrown away the revision history, and done a bzr add *; bzr push.

Comment: Yes. It would be simpler if you didn't want to hoard the revision history.